How to get the first letter from a filename in windows commandline?
I have just tried to remove the first character from a list of filenames but it does not work:
for %f in (_Telerik.Windows.*.dll) do set "filename=%f" && ren "%f" "%filename:~1%"

Result:
C:\Directory\set "filename=_Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8Touch.dll"   && ren "_Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8Touch.dll" "Telerik.Windows.Zip.dll"
A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.

C:\Directory\set "filename=_Telerik.Windows.Zip.dll"   && ren "_Telerik.Windows.Zip.dll" "Telerik.Windows.Zip.dll"
A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.

For your information, I have already used setlocal enabledelayedexpansion.
How can I get that first underscore from those filenames?

enabledelayedexpansion doesn't alter the way %variables% work – it introduces a whole new syntax, !variable!, as a separate expansion step.
So if you want a Cmd one-liner, then use !filename:~1!.
Beware that the delayed !variables! sometimes expand too late; in particular, if a regular %variable% happens to have any ! in its expanded value, that too will be processed by delayed expansion.
If this goes into a .bat or .cmd script, it might be more reliable to call a subroutine instead:
setlocal
for %%f in (_Telerik.Windows.*.dll) do call :rename "%%~f"
goto :eof

:rename
set "filename=%~1"
ren "%filename%" "%filename:~1%"
goto :eof

or to use PowerShell:
PS>  dir _Telerik.Windows.*.dll | % { mv $_ $_.Name.Substring(1) }

